# Utility panels, gas pipe and building an extension

Tags: utilities, extension, access-panel

I've found a property I want to buy, renovate and put a side extension on. 
The side I want to extend currently has utility boxes on the external wall eg gas meter and I think also the gas pipe entry to the house might be there. What do I need to consider during extension? 
Can I just build a cupboard around the panels so they aren't an eyesore in the room or do they need to remain accessible from outside the house?
Thanks :)

Comment: A gas meter has a pressure regulator which must be outside for intake air and the possibility of a rupture.

Answer (score 4):

## Gas

The gas meter will have to be relocated.

The gas company may handle the plumbing up to the meter, but you'll be responsible for extending the indoor plumbing to the new location.  The gas may be off for a few days, while the relocation is completed, pressure tested, and inspected.

## Water

Depending on the supplier and local requirements, the water meter may not have to be relocated.  You'll have to ask your specific utility.

## Electric

The electric meter will also likely have to be relocated.

As with the gas, the utility may handle the service conductors, but you'll be responsible for anything after the meter.

Comment: Seems like water meter and electric would always have to be outside so they could be read/disconnected without needing access to the home/building.

Comment: @JPhi1618 You're right about electric (I was thinking service panel, instead of meter, first some reason).  In colder climates, water meters are installed indoors, where it's warm.